# 0.80.3/[BreezeController]-Error

Tags: breeze

just updated to the new Version 0.80.3 of Breeze from Version 0.78.3. With the new version i get this in Fiddler:

```
500  localhost:50372  /api/Breeze/Metadata


{"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.",
"ExceptionType":"System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException",
"StackTrace":"   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
at Breeze.WebApi.BreezeConfig.<get_Instance>b__1(Assembly a)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Breeze.WebApi.BreezeConfig.get_Instance()
at Breeze.WebApi.JsonFormatter.Create()
at Breeze.WebApi.BreezeControllerAttribute..cctor()"
}
```

I had the [BreezeController] Attribute before. Problem seems to be the JSON Serializer. With just [ODataActionFilter] i get the Metadata but thats not enough.

I read the Docs but i do not think i missed a change. Using a Backup of 0.78.3 it works again. Any ideas here? 
And: "Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property". How do i get these?

Thanks

Comment: In 80.3 we use assembly probing on the server to find an instance of any BreezeConfig subclasses.  It looks like this code is failing when trying to reflect over one of your referenced assemblies.  Can you try with 80.2 because this code does not perform the same probing.   (all old versions are available at the bottom of the breeze download page) If this works, please let me know, and I will try to get a fix out that skips over any assemblies that can't be reflected over.

Comment: Its working with 0.80.2. Thanks for the info. Am i missing a reference in my project? Everything works...

Comment: Sascha - I don't believe so. We just need to update the server-side probing logic to better handle exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and is fixed in v 0.80.5.  Please let us know of any issues.